# Android lint does not report deprecated dependencies

Tags: android, lint

If I mark some class or function with `@Deprecated` I would wish Lint to report all usages of this class as warning, however I cant see in Lint html report anything related do Deprecated usages.

I tried setting

`<issue id="Deprecated" severity="warning" />`

in lint.xml configuration file, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Lint doesn't support detecting deprecated usages. Use Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA for warnings on deprecated code. Enable "Java | Code issues | Usage of deprecated members" in Inspections settings. Alternatively, use third-party tools like Checkstyle or Error Prone.